# LetsEncrypt doesn't want to validate my domain

Tags: nginx, lets-encrypt

This has been bugging me for the last couple of days, and I just can't seem to figure out what is going on. I have a new server I setup (using [Vesta](http://vestacp.com/), with nginx). They have a built-in tool for using *LetsEncrypt*, and supposedly this has worked:

[image]

...and then the domain being edited:

[image]

The **snginx.conf** file has the settings in (and those files do indeed exist):

```
ssl_certificate      /home/admin/conf/web/ssl.steampj.com.pem;
ssl_certificate_key  /home/admin/conf/web/ssl.steampj.com.key;
```

I also have this when defining the `server {`  bit:

```
server {
    listen      443 ssl;
    listen      [::]:443 ssl;
```

I get no errors when restarting/reloading nginx. You when you go here, you get an error: https://steampj.com/

[image]

and:[image]

I'm baffled as to why it's not working

Here is the full `server {}` condition for that domain:

```
server {
    listen      443 ssl;
    listen      [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name steampj.com www.steampj.com;
    root        /home/admin/web/steampj.com/public_html;
    index       index.php index.html index.htm;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/domains/steampj.com.log combined;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/domains/steampj.com.bytes bytes;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/domains/steampj.com.error.log error;

    ssl_certificate      /home/admin/conf/web/ssl.steampj.com.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  /home/admin/conf/web/ssl.steampj.com.key;

    location / {

        location ~* ^.+\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif|bmp|ico|svg|css|js)$ {
            expires     max;
        }

        location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
                return  404;
            }

            fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9005;
            fastcgi_index   index.php;
            include         /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        }
    }

    error_page  403 /error/404.html;
    error_page  404 /error/404.html;
    error_page  500 502 503 504 /error/50x.html;

    location /error/ {
        alias   /home/admin/web/steampj.com/document_errors/;
    }

    location ~* "/\.(htaccess|htpasswd)$" {
        deny    all;
        return  404;
    }

    location /vstats/ {
        alias   /home/admin/web/steampj.com/stats/;
        include /home/admin/web/steampj.com/stats/auth.conf*;
    }

    include     /etc/nginx/conf.d/phpmyadmin.inc*;
    include     /etc/nginx/conf.d/phppgadmin.inc*;
    include     /etc/nginx/conf.d/webmail.inc*;

    include     /home/admin/conf/web/snginx.steampj.com.conf*;
}
```

I did wonder if maybe the firewall was blocking, but it seems to be set as open in `ufw`:

```
root@com:~# ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
8181                       ALLOW       Anywhere
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere
8181 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

and then:

```
root@com:~# lsof -OnP | grep LISTEN
nginx      2382                     root   22u     IPv4              95181      0t0        TCP 213.219.38.44:443 (LISTEN)
nginx      2382                     root   45u     IPv6             264609      0t0        TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
nginx      2637                 www-data   22u     IPv4              95181      0t0        TCP 213.219.38.44:443 (LISTEN)
nginx      2637                 www-data   45u     IPv6             264609      0t0        TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
nginx      2638                 www-data   22u     IPv4              95181      0t0        TCP 213.219.38.44:443 (LISTEN)
nginx      2638                 www-data   45u     IPv6             264609      0t0        TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
```

**UPDATE 2:** I managed to get the ipv6 stuff going with http. It was the `ufw` blocking the port for some reason (disabled it, and ts fine... which is OK as we have iptables and fail2ban anyway)

I still can't get it to connect with openssl or curl on ipv4 though :/

```
root@steamdev2:~# curl -Iv4 https://steampj.com/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 213.219.38.44...
* Connected to steampj.com (213.219.38.44) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS Unknown, Unknown (22):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol


root@steamdev2:~# openssl s_client -connect steampj.com:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
139846633119256:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:s23_clnt.c:794:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 315 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
---
```

**UPDATE 3:** I'm not sure if this could be the issue, but I noticed that my other server (that I setup a couple of weeks ago), is using nginx **1.10.0**, whereas this new one is using **1.11.13** ... maybe there is a bug?

Comment: "You when you go here, you get an error" - what kind of error do you get ? please describe it.

Comment: @sfk - do you not get an error? I've added some screenshots in for what I get in FF/Chrome. Apologies, I just assumed everyone would get the error, so didn't bother actually posting it =)

Comment: It actually works for me :

`curl -I https://steampj.com/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Sat, 08 Apr 2017 08:43:34 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 1045
Last-Modified: Fri, 07 Apr 2017 14:13:42 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
ETag: "58e79e96-415"
Accept-Ranges: bytes`

Comment: @sfk - what do you get with: `openssl s_client -connect steampj.com:443 2>/dev/null </dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -enddate` ? curl loads for me, but the browser doesn't (or https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=https://www.steampj.com )

Comment: Ok, it seems that it works for me with IPv6 (default for me) `curl -Iv6 https://steampj.com/` but not with `curl -Iv4 https://steampj.com/`

Comment: Mmmm odd. I've added the full `server {}` section for that domain in my post. Does that help at all? I'm sure I have it correct with `listen 443 ssl;    listen      [::]:443 ssl;`. Popping out for a bit, back in a little while :)

Comment: "This server could not prove that it is steampj.com; its security certificate is from com.steampunkjunkies.com. This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection." - You need to request the certificate for the domain you serve

Comment: @ptman - huh? The certificate works fine with ipv6, but not ipv4. Where are you seeing that message?

Comment: I typed steampj.com into my browser, but trying now it seems to work.

Comment: @ptman - so it works for you in the browser? I still get the "not safe" error message. The stupid thing, is that it DOESNT work with:  `curl -Iv4 https://steampj.com/`, yet it does on ipv6:  `curl -Iv6 https://steampj.com/` .. I just don't understand why :/

Comment: yes, first it didn't work, but now it does.

Comment: @ptman - mmm, what the heck! Still not working for me (in any browser, and https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=https://www.steampj.com also tells me its broken). Eugh :/

Comment: FYI, when using http instead of https, the problem is with ipv6 (ipv4 is fine). So exactly the opposite behavior than with https. So I assume that nginx still requires `ipv6only` option with the `listen [::]`directives. See here for additional guidelines https://bashelton.com/2014/02/nginx-v1-4-5-and-ipv6/

Comment: @sfk - mmm odd, the prot thickens! I didn't even bother checking the non-ssl version, as I just assumed that was fine. I'll have to do some more digging tomorrow. So frustrating!

Comment: @sfk - I found the issue with the non-ssl not working on ipv6. It was the ubuntu firewall blocking it. However, the issue still exists with accessing the ssl version on ipv4 :( I've added "**update 2**" above... does that give any other hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your certificate seems to work just fine, even on Android that has strict policy.

As based on comments:

- Almost everyone else sees the certificate ok now.
- You still get errors.
- LetsEncypt couldn't still validate it.

I checked your `SOA` serial, which is `2017040741` from yesterday and your `TTL` is set to 24 hours. The problem is most likely that there's wrong IP address in the DNS cache of your *recursive DNS server*, as well as the one LetsEncrypt uses. (Anyone helping you hasn't cached it before.)

Try again tomorrow. From here, It's also possible to use shorter `TTL`, e.g. `21600` for 6 hours.

---

**UPDATE:** Yesterday the certificate seemed to be fine but now I have `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`.

With verbose mode of `curl` I can see the actual problem:

```
curl -v -ipv4 https://steampj.com/
* About to connect() to steampj.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 213.219.38.44...
* connected
* Connected to steampj.com (213.219.38.44) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
* Closing connection #0
curl: (35) error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
```

You usually get `SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO` when there's something else listening on port 443. In most cases this happens when HTTPD is listening on port 443 without SSL, but this time that's not the case, because you get `ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE` from http://steampj.com:443/, and as netcat shows:

```
nc -v steampj.com 443
DNS fwd/rev mismatch: steampj.com != li1097-44.members.linode.com
steampj.com [213.219.38.44] 443 (https) open
GET / HTTP/1.1
▒▒▒PuTTY
```

As your `nginx` was listening to port 443 based on `lsof -OnP | grep LISTEN` the problem is most likely in the Nginx configuration.

1. Check whether you have another `server {}` section unnecessarily having `listen 443` and remove it. Also that I had `CApath: /etc/ssl/certs` instead of configured `/home/admin/conf/web/` suggests the same.
2. **Check that you surely have `ipv6only=on`.** You have:

   ```
   server {
       listen      443 ssl;
       listen      [::]:443 ssl;
   ```

   According to Nginx ngx_http_core_module documentation on [Directive `listen`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen):

   > **ipv6only=on|off**
   >
   > this parameter (0.7.42) determines (via the `IPV6_V6ONLY` socket option)
   >   whether an IPv6 socket listening on a wildcard address `[::]` will accept
   >   only IPv6 connections or both IPv6 and IPv4 connections. This parameter
   >   is turned on by default. It can only be set once on start.

   Despite that by default this option should be `on`, you should see whether it is set `off` somewhere in the configuration and update both your `server {` sections to have:

   ```
   server {
       listen   443 ssl;
       listen   [::]:443 ipv6only=on ssl;
   ```

   As this parameter can only be set once on start, it's crucial to have it `on` on the `default_server` configuration as will also affect all further `server`s.

Comment: Mmm thats an interesting point. The DNS *was* set to "default", but I changed it to "300 (5 minutes)" yesterday. I'll give it a whirl on monday, to see if it helped :) Fortunately this is only a test domain (to make sure the server is ready to put live sites on), so I'm hoping that's all it is

Comment: Your NOW have shorter `TTL` in `steampj.com. 300 IN A` but still the longer in `steampj.com. 86400 IN AAAA` and in `SOA` minimum TTL. But the most important thing is that if already cached, TTL change only applies after the seconds current TTL has left in the cache.

Comment: @Esa_Jokien , unfortunately that didn't work :( The "curl" test query works fine for ipv6, but not ipv4. Both of them return the IP I'm expecting: `curl -Iv4 https://steampj.com/` and `curl -Iv6 https://steampj.com/` ... this is so frustrating. I've never had any issues like this before with nginx :(

Comment: Is there another `server {}` sections having `listen 443`? IPv4 on `213.219.38.44:443` now gives `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`, while yesterday it worked just fine.

Comment: @Esa_Jokinen yes, there is (2 `server {}` bits in this .conf). One is for steamj.com and the other for com.steampunkjunkies.com). I've commented one of them out, and in the steampj.com one I have: `listen [::]:443 ssl; listen 443 ssl;` ... still no joy though :/  Right, I'm off for a bike ride to de-stress!

Comment: @Esa_Jokinen thanks for the suggestion. I'm using VestaCP to manage this. It creates /home/admin/conf/web/[nginx & snginx].conf files. One for standard, and the other for ssl. You mentioned about Apache ... is there somewhere I can check? We do have Apache2.4 on there as a reverse proxy for the Perl scripts

Comment: I added a third thing to check: add `ipv6only=on` parameter to your `listen   [::]:443 ipv6only=on ssl;` on all your `server {` sections and restart Nginx. That'll probably fix this.

Comment: @Esa_Jokinen thanks, but no joy. Isn't that set to "on" by default now anyway? (from what I was reading on the 1.11.0 release blog article)

Comment: Yes, it SHOULD be set `on` by default as described on official documentation. Then, many unofficial tutorials mention that there have been problems and you have to manually set it.

Comment: @Esa_Jokinen ah ok. Unfortunately it didn't help though :(

Answer (score 0):

Ok well this isn't really an "answer" as such, but I have managed to get it working.

I started from scratch, and re-installed **VestaCP** from scratch with:

```
curl -O http://vestacp.com/pub/vst-install.sh

bash vst-install.sh --nginx yes --apache yes --phpfpm no --named no --remi yes --vsftpd yes --proftpd no --iptables yes --fail2ban yes --quota no --exim yes --dovecot yes --spamassassin yes --clamav yes --mysql yes --postgresql no --hostname com.mysite.com --email andy.newby@xxx.com --password xxx
```

I then edited /usr/local/vesta/data/templates/web/nginx/default.tpl, so it also had:

```
listen      [%ip%]:%proxy_port% ssl;
```

(for some reason it only has IPv4 there, not sure why).

I then went in and setup the domain, and voila -- it worked!

Comment: So actually it must have been one of the conditions mentioned in my answer, but the Nginx configuration was tampered by a web hosting control panel making it impossible to find the cause without complete re-install. There are good reasons why [Serverfault doesn't give support for web hosting control panels](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8094/where-can-i-ask-questions-about-web-hosting-control-panels).

Comment: @EsaJokinen - ah I wasn't aware that was a case on Serverfault. Although, this wasn't really a CP issue, but an nginx one (the config files look the same as I was using before, but they just "work" now). Thanks for your help though :)